# Vim - run ant command with current file as an argument

Tags: vim, ant

In my IDE (webstorm) I have configured an external tool to run ant like so:

```
ant myTarget -DfileNoExt="$FileNameWithoutExtension$"
```

the `$FileNameWithoutExtension$` is expanded by the IDE when the command is run.

I am transitioning to using Vim. I am a Vim n00b.

How do I do the same with Vim (MacVim specifically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim will expand `%` as the current file. You can use modifiers on it (see `:help filename-modifiers`). You can tell vim to use ant as your make program:

```
compiler ant
setlocal makeprg=ant\ myTarget\ -DfileNoExt=\"%:t:r\"
```

Now you can use `:make` to build your current file. You should get build errors in your quickfix (view it with `:copen`).

You probably want to put the above script into a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`. That will load it for every java file you open.

---

Note that if you want to use different targets, `:make` will pass all arguments to ant. So `:make otherTarget` will execute `ant myTarget -DfileNoExt="file" otherTarget`.

Answer (score 2):

you can map either Hotkey or Your own key-sequence in vim.rc(not sure in mac, should have similar resource file)

add this line to your vim resource file:

```
imap <F5> <ESC><ESC>:!ant mytarget -Dfilenoext=\"%<\"
```

which means when you editing the source code, press F5 will run your ant tool
for more, you can read http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Compile_Java_with_Sun_JDK_javac and http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=155